# add/remove a class from an element with getElementsByClassName in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to add/remove a class .active on an element but it won't work and i don't know what is wrong

```
<div class="test">aa</div>

  <style>
     .active {
        background-color: #000;
     }
  </style>

  <script>

  var nico = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

  for (i=0; i<nico.length; i++) {
     nico[i].onclick = function() {

        this.classList.add('active');

        if(this.classList.contains('active')) {
           this.classList.remove('active');
        }
     }
  }

  </script>
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Your logic will always remove the `active` class

Comment: you add and then immediately remove the same class. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **onclick** callback you're always running first:

```
    this.classList.add('active');
```

before actually checking if the element contains the class:

```
    if(this.classList.contains('active')) {
       this.classList.remove('active');
    }
```

You should create some toggle logic like:

```
    if(this.classList.contains('active')) {
       this.classList.remove('active');
    } else {
       this.classList.add('active');
    }
```

and remove the first `this.classList.add('active');` sentence

hope this helps

Comment: `classList` has a built-in `toggle` method that does this.